# Wrong Foreach cycle

Tags: php, foreach, cycle

i am doing something wrong with my foreach cycle.  But looks my knowledge is not enugh to figure out what's wrong. My code is pretty simple:

```
   $xnl_file = "xml.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xnl_file);
    $my_file = 0;
    foreach ($xml as $value){
        var_dump($value);
        $CountryOrganizationId = "<CountryOrganizationId>".$xml->Partnership->CountryOrganizationId."</CountryOrganizationId>";
        $PartnershipId = "<PartnershipId>".$xml->Partnership->PartnershipId."</PartnershipId>";
        $OwnerId = "<OwnerId>".$xml->Partnership->OwnerId."<OwnerId>";
        $PartnerIdList = "<PartnerIdList><String>".$xml->Partnership->PartnerIdList->String."</String></PartnerIdList>";
        $CountryOrganizationId_contact = "<Contract><CountryOrganizationId>".$xml->Partnership->Contract->CountryOrganizationId."</CountryOrganizationId>";
        $ContractId = "<ContractId>".$xml->Partnership->Contract->ContractId."</ContractId>";
        $data = "<Partnership>".$CountryOrganizationId.$PartnershipId.$OwnerId.$PartnerIdList.$CountryOrganizationId_contact.$ContractId.$Role1.$Category1.$Rate1.
        $Role2.$Category2.$Rate2.$Role3.$Category3.$Rate3."</Partnership>";
        echo $data;

}
```

I am getting data from XML and try to parse it on multiple one, but this just copy same data again and again.  I am not sure what i am doing wrong. In my opinion data should rewrite each other every time cycle is doing same but they are not changing. At echo $data i get as many results as i should, problem is just they are same.

If I var_dump $value at start i get nice result that data are coming to cycle but why the output is the same all the time?

Please can somebody give me advise?

Thanks

Comment: What are trying to achieve? I would suggest you to have a look at what the function `simplexml_load_file` is returning. If you post the output here, we would be more able to help. But please specify a question.

Comment: It looks like you are using $xml instead of $value->Partnership in your loop.

Comment: Output is like this:

`CZContract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04EMM-O-BDD15299MM-O-2A10BCFCZContract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04ELabor1250.0Paint2350.0Labor1250.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------

CZContract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04EMM-O-BDD15299MM-O-2A10BCFCZContract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04ELabor1250.0Paint2350.0Labor1250.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------

CZContract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04EMM-O-BDD15299MM-O-2A10BCFCZContract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04ELabor1250.0Paint2350.0Labor1250.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $value variable is never used, you're always using the $xml. Try it like:

```
$xnl_file = "xml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xnl_file);
$my_file = 0;
foreach ($xml as $value){
    var_dump($value);
    $CountryOrganizationId         = "<CountryOrganizationId>" . $value->CountryOrganizationId . "</CountryOrganizationId>";
    $PartnershipId                 = "<PartnershipId>" . $value->PartnershipId . "</PartnershipId>";
    $OwnerId                       = "<OwnerId>" . $value->OwnerId . "<OwnerId>";
    $PartnerIdList                 = "<PartnerIdList><String>" . $value->PartnerIdList->String . "</String></PartnerIdList>";
    $CountryOrganizationId_contact = "<Contract><CountryOrganizationId>" . $value->Contract->CountryOrganizationId . "</CountryOrganizationId>";
    $ContractId                    = "<ContractId>" . $value->Contract->ContractId . "</ContractId>";
    $data                          = "<Partnership>" . $CountryOrganizationId . $PartnershipId . $OwnerId . $PartnerIdList . $CountryOrganizationId_contact . 
                                     $ContractId . $Role1 . $Category1 . $Rate1 . $Role2 . $Category2 . $Rate2 . $Role3 . $Category3 . $Rate3 . 
                                    "</Partnership>"afdsf

    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. Of Course it have logic and i understand what you mean. Problem is that this throw me error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object :(

Comment: Can you please post the output of var_dump($value);

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VM4EaDh7

I throw it to pastebin because its pretty big text and wasn't able to add it to comment.

This value is of course for each part of XML

Comment: I've updated the code. Basically while you foreach, you foreach over each Partnership element, which is the current element inside the loop. You need to replace every occurrence of $value->Partnership->{something_else} with $value->{something_else}.

Answer (score -2):

Concat $data to its previous value { $data .= "......"}

```
foreach ($xml as $value)
{
        var_dump($value);
        $CountryOrganizationId = "<CountryOrganizationId>".$xml->Partnership->CountryOrganizationId."</CountryOrganizationId>";
        $PartnershipId = "<PartnershipId>".$xml->Partnership->PartnershipId."</PartnershipId>";
        $OwnerId = "<OwnerId>".$xml->Partnership->OwnerId."<OwnerId>";
        $PartnerIdList = "<PartnerIdList><String>".$xml->Partnership->PartnerIdList->String."</String></PartnerIdList>";
        $CountryOrganizationId_contact = "<Contract><CountryOrganizationId>".$xml->Partnership->Contract->CountryOrganizationId."</CountryOrganizationId>";
        $ContractId = "<ContractId>".$xml->Partnership->Contract->ContractId."</ContractId>";

        $data .= "<Partnership>".$CountryOrganizationId.$PartnershipId.$OwnerId.$PartnerIdList.$CountryOrganizationId_contact.$ContractId.$Role1.$Category1.$Rate1.
        $Role2.$Category2.$Rate2.$Role3.$Category3.$Rate3."</Partnership>";
}
 echo $data;
```